# Where does the ASP.NET Core logging API as default store logs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In the ASP.NET Core 2.0, I use the [default logging API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x). My app is hosted as an Azure Web App.

**My question: Where are these outputted? And how do I modify it?**

(I don't need them in my database or file system for now, just read the recent logs for some debugging).

**WHAT I AM DOING:**

In my `Startup.cs` file I have injected the logging:

```
private readonly ILogger<Startup> _logger;

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

And I then write a couple of:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Configure RUNNING");
```

However, I haven't been able to find any of these in a log inside FTP/Azure portal.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398453/asp-net-core-azure-web-app-logging?rq=1

Comment: The default logger logs to Console window. If you run your application on self hosted mode you will see the logs. And in some point; thoose logs are it is accessible by application insight. But not sure about app insight :)

Comment: While [WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.0) configures the console and debug window, *your* application nees to specify where to log. You can add file targets, databases, buckets, AppInsights, third-party services etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So to clearify. Say I want to use the Azure web diagnostics. I need to goto Program.cs, add ConfigureLogging and specify the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices ?

Comment: I've found the official documentation to be incredibly helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After playing around for an hour, I got to understand how it plays together in asn ASP.NET Core app.

First of all, i would recommend watching this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icwD6xkyrsc .

How to solve it

**STEP 1:**

Go to your `Startup.cs` class. Inside the `Configure` method, make sure it has the following signature:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
```

Mine did not have the `ILoggerFactory`. However, you need to add this one. It's by default injected into the class by ASP.NET Core.

**STEP 2:**

Set up your provider.

I setup the following two:

```
loggerFactory.AddDebug();
loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
```

The AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics comes from [the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices) Ojisah mentioned in his answer.

**STEP 3:**

Now we can start logging.

Example in my `HomeController`:

```
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("TEST INDEX LOGGER");
        return View();
    }
```

**STEP 4: Make sure your log level matches your expectations**

Look at your `appsettings.json` to make sure the warning level matches your expectations:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

**STEP 5: See the logs**

In Azure, I have been setting up the `Diagnostics logs` tab, I've set this up so it logs to my blobs:

[image]

**STEP 6:**

Now you can download and see the log files which is inside your BLOB.

Example from my log file where we can see the log from my `HomeController`:

```
2018-03-05 14:15:32.489 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action Likvido.Website.Main.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Likvido.Website.Main) in 1.6257ms
2018-03-05 14:15:32.489 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 2.0892ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
2018-03-05 14:15:32.608 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/js/site.min.js  
2018-03-05 14:15:32.610 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 2.0154ms 302 
2018-03-05 14:15:32.844 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://likvido.dk/js/site.min.js  
2018-03-05 14:15:32.845 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 0.571ms 404 
2018-03-05 14:15:46.878 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/  
2018-03-05 14:15:46.878 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing action method Likvido.Website.Main.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Likvido.Website.Main) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
2018-03-05 14:15:46.878 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Controllers.HomeController: TEST INDEX LOGGER
2018-03-05 14:15:46.878 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor: Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.
2018-03-05 14:15:46.878 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action Likvido.Website.Main.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Likvido.Website.Main) in 0.7351ms
2018-03-05 14:15:46.879 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 0.996ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
2018-03-05 14:15:47.518 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/js/site.min.js  
2018-03-05 14:15:47.520 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 1.6787ms 302 
2018-03-05 14:15:47.617 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://likvido.dk/js/site.min.js  
2018-03-05 14:15:47.617 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 0.628ms 404
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add providers as mentioned later in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    webHost.Run();
}
```

For azure you can use the Azure App Service provider (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices)

```
logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I still have a bit trouble getting it to work. So in my ASP.NET CORE example, I need to do exactly what? Is this inside Startup class and Configure method?

Comment: No, this isn't in the `Startup` class: this is done in the `Main` method of your web app.

Comment: In the Main method in the Program.cs file