# Inject instance of ILogger in my component class Azure Functions using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, azure-functions, autofac-configuration

I am writing a simple Azure function.

I have installed the `AzureFunctions.Autofac` nuget package, and would like to use this as my `DI` library.

I have set up the following `AutofacConfig` class to register my types:

```
public class AutofacConfig
{
    public AutofacConfig(string functionName)
    {
        DependencyInjection.Initialize(builder =>
        {
            //do all of you initialization here

            //db client
            builder.RegisterType<EventComponent>()
            .As<IComponent<EventModel>>().SingleInstance(); 
        }, functionName);
    }
}
```

Here is my `EventComponent` class, to which I would like to inject the `ILogger` instance provided.

```
public class EventComponent : IComponent<EventModel>
{
    private ILogger _log;

    public EventComponent(ILogger logger)
    {
        _log = logger;
    }
}
```

Here is how I inject my EventComponent:

```
[FunctionName("AddEvent")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log, [Inject]IComponent<EventModel> component)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        await component.Add(new EventModel() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Description = $"Test description nr: {new Random().Next(1, 100000)}", User = "Test User" });

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

The problem is, I get an exception on the above, because `Autofac` cannot resolve the parameter Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.

Here is the exception message:

> Exception binding parameter 'component'... Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger)'. (See inner exception for details.) -> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Event.Function.Components.EventComponent' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger)'.",

How can I inject the `ILogger` instance into my `EventComponent` class?

Comment: Have you tried using `builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();`? Obviously you need to register a logger and you should do it using the autofac builder and before you register your `EventComponent` class.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado What does Logger represent?  I do not have a Logger class, and if I want to use the defualt Logger class provided by Intellisense, I need to pass a Type to the generic Logger class

Comment: You need to pass an implementation of `ILogger` which can be your own implementation. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112636/6138713) answer as reference.

Comment: Why are you even using an `ILogger` in your `EventComponent` class when you are not familiar with the `ILogger` itself? Is it not possible to remove the reference?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado the .NET SDK provides a default implementation for ILogger, which Logs to Application Insights, and I would like to make use of the default logging in my component class.

Comment: Then you should register that default implementation for `ILogger` using autofac builder.

Answer (score 2):

In Azure Functions V2, the ILogger is injected by default. Also, here are two very nice articles on dependency inject in Azure Functions. 
https://blog.mexia.com.au/dependency-injections-on-azure-functions-v2

and http://codingsoul.de/2018/01/19/azure-function-dependency-injection-with-autofac/

Answer (score 1):

I found your question when looking for the same thing. Have you found a solution?

Because I don't think that is possible. ILogger log is injected by the framework and I don't see how it could be referenced from your AutofacConfig-class.

How I resolved this was by changing the EventComponent-class to use Setter-injection instead of Constructor-injection, like this:

```
public class EventComponent : IComponent<EventModel>
{
    public ILogger Log { get; set; }    
}
```

and change your function to set the Log-property:

```
[FunctionName("AddEvent")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log, [Inject]IComponent<EventModel> component)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        component.Log = log;
        await component.Add(new EventModel() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Description = $"Test description nr: {new Random().Next(1, 100000)}", User = "Test User" });

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

The downside is that you need to remember to set that value at the start of every function that uses that class, but the injection works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject the ILogger into a function app you need to do the following:

1. Add the correct log level and namespace to your host.json

   ```
    {
       "version": "2.0",
       "logging": {
            "applicationInsights": {
                "samplingSettings": {
                    "isEnabled": true
          }
        },
       "logLevel": {
           "YourNameSpace": "Information"
    }
   ```
2. Inject `ILogger<T>` where T is your function app class name/type. In this sample my function app class name is Api.

   ```
    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Api> _logger;

        public TestService(ILogger<Api> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void LogSomething(string message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(message);
        }
    }
   ```